# Django Python - How to add foreign key to table displayed in admin page

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin, auto-increment

So I got 4 tables in a MySQL database.
The database is managed with Django under an app I created with Django. 
Here are 2 of the 4 classes in the file models.py corresponding to the database tables:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Pdb(models.Model):
    id_pdb_chain = models.CharField(db_column='id_PDB_chain', primary_key=True, max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_pdb = models.CharField(db_column='id_PDB', max_length=4)  # Field name made lowercase.
    chaine = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sequence_proteine = models.TextField(db_column='sequence_Proteine')  # Field name made lowercase.
    start_seq = models.IntegerField()
    taille_proteine = models.IntegerField(db_column='taille_Proteine')  # Field name made lowercase.
    resolution_pdb = models.FloatField(db_column='resolution_PDB')  # Field name made lowercase.
    meth_res = models.ForeignKey('MethodesRes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='meth_Res')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id_pdb

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PDB'

class StructSec(models.Model):
    id_struct_sec = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_pred = models.IntegerField()
    structure_predite = models.TextField(db_column='structure_Predite')  # Field name made lowercase.
    nombre_ppii = models.IntegerField(db_column='nombre_PPII')  # Field name made lowercase.
    pourcentage_ppii = models.FloatField(db_column='pourcentage_PPII')  # Field name made lowercase.
    angle_phi = models.TextField()
    angle_psi = models.TextField()
    id_pdb_chain = models.ForeignKey(Pdb, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_PDB_chain')  # Field name made lowercase.
    nom_analyse = models.ForeignKey(MethodesAnalyse, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='nom_Analyse')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.structure_predite

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'struct_sec'
```

As you can see I already found a way to display a field for each table in the admin page with this part in each table:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.structure_predite
```

But when I want to replace "structure_predite" this by the primary key in the "StructSec" class like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id_struct_sec
```

Django return this error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

I also have to mention that I have made few modifications in the "admin.py" file here it is:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Pdb, MethodesAnalyse, MethodesRes, StructSec


class PdbInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Pdb

class PdbAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id_pdb','header','chaine','taille_proteine','meth_res')
    list_filter = ['chaine','meth_res']
    search_fields = ['id_pdb_chain','header']


class MethodesAnalyseInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MethodesAnalyse

class MethodesAnalyseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nom_analyse')


class MethodesResInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MethodesRes

class MethodesResAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('meth_res')


class StructSecInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MethodesRes

class StructSecAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id_struct_sec','nombre_PPII','pourcentage_PPII','id_PDB','nom_Analyse')
    search_fields = ['nombre_ppii','pourcentage_ppii']


admin.site.register(Pdb,PdbAdmin)
admin.site.register(MethodesAnalyse)
admin.site.register(MethodesRes)
admin.site.register(StructSec)
```

Knowing this, my question is simple:
How to display the autoincremented IDs (Primary Key) from the class StructSec in the corresponding admin table without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sijan answer is correct, I will just add that, to make links work, you may also have to do this:

```
 def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id_struct_sec)
```

Without the "str()" in the return, links don't work and return errors when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is raising due to None value. Python cannot convert None.

Replace your unicode definition to 'str' as:

```
 def __str__(self):
      return self.id_struct_sec
```

Comment: The answer is correct, I will just add that to make links works you also have to do this :

     def __str__(self):
          return self.id_struct_sec

Comment: Great. I didn't try that. But, yeah str() will give you the right result.